# How to insert a row after a row that has a checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to insert a row directly after the row that is checked. The HTML is listed below and here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgayheart/t3gew8L0/). Basically if row 1 is checked I need to insert a row between row 1 and row 2 or if the last row is checked I need to append a new row. I was able to write a script that adds a row to the end of the table, but it wasn't what I needed.

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('requestTable')" />

<TABLE id="requestTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Example column</th>
    <th>Example column 2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example1" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example2" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example1" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example2" /></td>
  </tr>
</TABLE>

<script>
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Share the script, please.

Comment: @uk1992 Currently in your fiddle, I can check the checkbox on both rows, what happens if both rows are checked, and I click add row?

Comment: I added the function to the question. I can't get it to work in JSFiddle, but it works in Chrome when I open it.

Comment: @RyanWilson I was hoping to make it do nothing or add a row after both using a loop. Either one works for now.

Comment: You should look into the `.closest()` and `.after()` functions of jQuery. Those will help you find the closest parent and insert after a specific element. Your current code does not really use jQuery despite it being tagged, though.

Comment: @uk1992 I created a new fiddle for you which allows your function to be called on clicking the add button (https://jsfiddle.net/kxr9wbn1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you asked: It will add a new row after the row which is checked, if more than one row is checked, it will not add a row:

**Html**: I modified this to have an id property on the add button for adding the event handler, and added a common className to your checkboxes.:

```
<INPUT id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Row" />

<TABLE id="requestTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Example column</th>
    <th>Example column 2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input class="chkInfo" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example1" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example2" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input class="chkInfo" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example1" /></td>
    <td><input name="Example2" /></td>
  </tr>
</TABLE>
```

**Script**:

```
//On DOM Ready add the click event to the Add Button
$(function(){
   //Uses JQuery's .on to add eventHandler to the button when the DOM is ready
   $('#btnAdd').on('click', function(){
      addRow("requestTable"); 
   });
});

//Modified the addRow metthod to look for the checked checkboxes
//with className of chkInfo, if the number of checked checkboxes is greater
//than 1 it does nothing, else it finds the parent row of the checkbox which is checked with JQuery's .closest()
//and uses JQuery's .after() to append the row after the checked row
function addRow(tableID) {
    const checkboxes = $('#' + tableID).find('.chkInfo:checked');
    if($(checkboxes).length === 1){
       const newRow = '<tr><td><input class="chkInfo" type="checkbox" /></td><td><input name="Example1" /></td><td><input name="Example2" /></td></tr>';
       $($(checkboxes)[0]).closest('tr').after(newRow);
    } else{
       return;
    }

}
```

Working JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lf5cbdt0/)

Comment: @uk1992 You're welcome. Hope the comments in the script section of my answer help you to understand what I did. If you have questions, feel free to ask.